# Looping - Submission Consistency

Tags: sql-server, loops

I have a table structured like this:

| SchoolId | YearTerm | Submitted |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2022-2 | 1 |
| 1 | 2022-3 | 1 |
| 1 | 2022-4 | 1 |
| 2 | 2022-1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2022-2 | 1 |
| 2 | 2022-4 | 1 |

I am trying to figure out how many YearTerms these schools have been submitting in a row so I wrote some logic that gives me this output:

| SchoolId | YearTerm | Submitted | SubmitOrder |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2022-2 | 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 2022-3 | 1 | 3 |
| 1 | 2022-4 | 1 | 4 |
| 2 | 2022-1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2022-2 | 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 2022-4 | 1 | 3 |

```
SELECT
G.*
,ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY SchoolId ORDER BY G.YearTerm ASC) SubmitOrder
FROM
(
    SELECT

    DISTINCT
    SchoolId
    ,YearTerm 
    ,1 Submitted
    FROM Table 
) G
```

The problem is that for schools that skip a YearTerm (in the picture above, SchoolId = 2 is getting credit for 3 consecutive submissions when in reality it should only be 2). The desired output I am looking for is:

| SchoolId | YearTerm | Submitted | SubmitOrder |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2022-2 | 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 2022-3 | 1 | 3 |
| 1 | 2022-4 | 1 | 4 |
| 2 | 2022-1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2022-2 | 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 2022-4 | 1 | 1 |

Because SchoolId = 2 did not submit in 2022-3, there submission in 2022-4 is now there first submission in chronological order.

Any help is much appreciated!

Write a loop to solve for submissions consistency.

Comment: @BogdanSahlean . English, please. It is *required* on the site. I have no idea what you're trying to tell them OP by "Buna No. Please", and I suspect they don't either.

Comment: Again, English, @BogdanSahlean . How does the OP "buna no"?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: *"Write a loop to solve for submissions consistency."* Why do you want to use a loop? These are awfully inefficient.

Comment: The loop is the only way I could think to do it. I've never posted a question here so sorry about the images, was unsure how to ask my question without including the images.

Comment: @Larnu Some folks need their commenting privilege revoked.

Comment: I have updated my post. I removed the images and I built in the tables. Apologies. Hope this clears things up.

Comment: Do you have a table that contains all the terms? I assume you have a school table, based on that you have an ID for it.

Comment: Yes I have both!

Comment: I'd consider normalising your data so that *Term* is its own column, not combined with Year - if you need to generate missing terms that would make things much easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this perhaps?

```sql
SELECT  SchoolID, YearTerm, Submitted
,   ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY SchoolID, Streak ORDER BY YearTerm) AS submissionStreakID
FROM    (
    SELECT  SUM(CASE WHEN RIGHT(YearTerm, 1) = '1' 
            THEN CASE WHEN prevTerm <> CONCAT((CAST(LEFT(YearTerm, 4) AS INT) - 1), '-1') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
            ELSE CASE WHEN prevTerm <> CONCAT(LEFT(YearTerm, 5), CAST(RIGHT(YearTerm, 1) AS INT) - 1) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
        END) OVER(PARTITION BY SchoolID ORDER BY YearTerm) AS streak
    ,   *
    FROM    (
        SELECT  *
        ,   LAG(YearTerm) OVER(PARTITION BY SchoolID ORDER BY YearTerm) AS prevTerm
        FROM
        (
            VALUES  (1, N'2022-1', 1)
            ,   (1, N'2022-2', 1)
            ,   (1, N'2022-3', 1)
            ,   (1, N'2022-4', 1)
            ,   (1, N'2023-2', 1)
            ,   (1, N'2023-3', 1)
            ,   (1, N'2024-1', 0)
            ,   (2, N'2022-1', 1)
            ,   (2, N'2022-2', 1)
            ,   (2, N'2022-4', 1)
        ) t (SchoolId,YearTerm,Submitted)
        WHERE   Submitted = 1
        ) x
    ) x
```

I check if current term follows the previous and if not, increments the "streak" group count. Then it's an easy ROW_NUMBER() that calculates where in the streak you are

Comment: The only problem with this solution is my actual table is 80,000 + rows so I would not be able to hardcode all of that. Thank you though!

Comment: Hmm, this was just example with your data. You have to change the VALUES part to a SELECT FROM <your table>?

Comment: Let me get back to you, I'll try and implement the solution now.

Comment: After implementation it just generates a columns of only 1s. I am trying to understand your solution a bit further, maybe I can manipulate it a bit further to get what I need.

Comment: perhaps your yearTerm doesn't look exactly like YYYY-Q format

Comment: Ahh you're right, apologies, mine looked like this "YYYY - Q". I updated the format to match and it works like a charm!!! THANK YOU!!!